# Display out of stock | but qty had value

Tags: magento-1.9, error, quantity

I was bulk import qty through csv, import successfully but in my site display out of stock, the thing is, my qty had value.

Comment: Enable stock management from your back end first. Go to system >> configuration >> Inventory

Comment: already enabled ... then how this error came

Answer (score 0):

please check below image and change value to `in stock` and your product will be display as `in stock`

Magento has two mechanism for `out of stock`

1) when you have qty less then 0

2) when you select Stock availability attribute as `out of stock`

when one of the condition became true magento shows product as `out of stock`

[image]

Comment: i already did what u suggested, no improvement

Comment: do Reindexing and try again

Comment: bro, i did all possibilities, but no use

Comment: check on store level scope may be at store level you have selected `out of stock`